# Add custom images in highstock series

Tags: charts, highcharts

Does anyone know how to add custom images in highstock?

I have tried but unable to add image. Here's a jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/o81u7rjm/1/) and here is the reference [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series%3Cflags%3E.shape).

Javascript Code

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        var year = new Date(data[data.length - 1][0]).getFullYear(); // Get year of last data point

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Exchange rate'
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data: data,
                id: 'dataseries',
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 4
                }
            }, {
                type: 'flags',
                data: [{
                    x: Date.UTC(year, 4, 28),
                }],
                onSeries: 'dataseries',
                // Here I used the custom image
                shape: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/snow.png)',
                //shape: 'circlepin',
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Custom image is working fine with highcharts. If there is any example related to this please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with **SVG based** charting solutions (like [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com)), it is always easier to render images **after** initializing the chart.

Push the series like this;

```
// Add flags.
series.push({
    "type": "flags",
    "onSeries": "dataseries",
    "shadow": false,
    "width": 32,
    "shape": "url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)",
    "data": [{
        "x": Date.UTC(year, 4, 28)
    }],
});
```

And make sure to use latest version of HighStock.js;

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/master/highstock.js"></script>
```

And this will be the result;

[image: Image in HighStock Chart]

Working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djsbbxp7/).

Comment: Thanks, the difference is the version of the highchart.js I have just pointed to github and it works fine.

Comment: image location has changed to https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png